# Avoid commander parser complaining when no arguments are present and just show helpInfo

Tags: javascript, node-commander

I'm migrating a package from a much older version of commander (v2.20.3)

```js
program.command(`install [pkg]`)
  .alias(`i`)
  .action(installPackageOrLocal)
  .option(`-S, --save`, `Save to dependencies`)
  .option(`-D, --save-dev`, `Save to devDependencies`)
  .option(`--production`, `Will not install modules listed in devDependencies`)
  .option(`--test`, `Exit with code 1 if package limits like maxPackagesNumber or maxSizeBites exceeded`);
```

I'd like for the default (when calling the CLI with no arguments at all) to continue being the display of the help and no erring out, but currently it errs with:

> .../npm-reflect/node_modules/.pnpm/commander@8.3.0/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:142
> const [, name, args] = nameAndArgs.match(/([^ ]+) *(.*)/);

I was able to get the mostly desired behavior by adding:

```js
program.command('help', {isDefault: true})
  .action(() => {
    program.help();
  })
  .command(`install [pkg]`)
  // ...
```

...but this seems to be polluting things in the help by listing a new "help" command. How can I avoid the parser complaining when no arguments are present yet without adding a new command?

Comment: The easiest way is check for no arguments yourself before calling parse(), and display help instead. Simple but effective.

Comment: I'll accept that as an answer, @shadowspawn , if you like.

Comment: I realised the error behaviour was unexpected when I reread your description. Added an "answer" anyway, but not the root of your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The default behaviour in latest Commander is to display the help if you have subcommands and do not specify a subcommand. Which sounds like what you want! Not sure how you are getting an error, you might want to open a Commander [issue](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues) for help.
2. In general, if you want some custom behaviour for no arguments then it may be simple and easy to check yourself before calling `parse()`. e.g.

```js
if (process.argv.length < 3)
  program.help(); // exits
program.parse(process.argv);
```